# Why we must handle exception for method not throwing exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, methods, handle, scjp

Given

```
public class ToBeTestHandleException{

static class A {
    void process() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
  }

static class B extends A {
    void process() {
        System.out.println("B ");
    }
   }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new B();
    a.process();
   }

  }
```

Why we should handle the exception at line (a.process()) ?.The method process of class B does not throw exception at all?
PS:This is an SCJP question.

Answer (score 4):

You've assigned your `B` instance to a variable of type `A`. Since `A.process()` throws the exception, your code needs to handle that possibility.

Imagine you pass your instance to another method that accepts `A`s:

```
public void doSomething(A a) {
  a.process; // <--- we don't know this is a B, so you are forced to 
             //      catch the exception
}
```

Comment: Great job Duncan Jones.Thank you very much for your answer.It's absolutely the correct one.Thanks again.